# SQL server service broker related rights issue

Tags: sql-server, access-rights

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stproc_ssb_send] (@iname varchar(20))
WITH EXECUTE AS 'xyz'
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DIALOG_HANDLE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @MSG varchar(max) 

SET @MSG='<MESSAGE>
        <test>' + @iname + '</test>
        </MESSAGE>'

    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
    FROM SERVICE START_PROC_PROCESS_SERVICE
    TO SERVICE 'EXECUTE_PROC_PROCESS_SERVICE'
    ON CONTRACT [PROC_PROCESS_CONTRACT]
    WITH ENCRYPTION= OFF;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
    MESSAGE TYPE PROC_PROCESS_MT(@MSG);

    END CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
END
```

error:

> Msg 15517, Level 16, State 1, Procedure [stproc_ssb_send], Line 0
>   Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "xyz"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission.

XYZ is db_owner/db_ddladmin for this database.

Comment: Is it also the user `xyz` that tries to create the procedure?

Comment: created using "sa" & getting error while running

Comment: No quick idea then, sorry. You may have better luck asking at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Sorry for giving you obvious information but did you go over the [EXECUTE AS Clause documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx), specifically the Remarks section? Maybe there's something you overlooked.